# The order of labels are wrong after batching when importing data from tfrecords

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a problem when importing data from tfrecords files. Each sample in the tfrecords consists of a feautures vector with lenght 100 and an one-hot label vector with length 13. I use the code below to import data from tfrecords, referring to the official guide https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

```
def read_data(examples):
    features = {"features": tf.FixedLenFeature([seq_len], tf.int64),
               "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([category], tf.int64)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(examples, features)
    return parsed_features['features'], parsed_features['label']

# get next batch of data and label
def next_batch(filename, batch_size):
    data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)
    data = data.map(read_data)
    data = data.batch(batch_size)
    iterator = data.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_data, next_label = iterator.get_next()
    return next_data, next_label

with tf.Session() as sess:
    filetrain = 'train.tfrecords'
    next_data, next_label = next_batch(filetrain, num_example_train)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    data = sess.run(next_data)
    label = sess.run(next_label)
```

The problem is that the order of labels becomes wrong after batching. And if I remove the code 'data = data.batch', everything is OK.

I think one possible reason is that the features and labels are batched independently. So I tried to parse the example after batching, but get an error "Input serialized must be a scalar". Please help me if your know how to deal with this problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am certain this is a duplicate, but I can't find the other question, so I'll answer here.

Your problem is calling `sess.run()` twice for the data and labels. **Whenever you call `sess.run`, your graph is evaluated** (i.e., a new batch is extracted and run through the graph until *all* the values of the tensors in the list you're passing as first argument to `run` is known).

Doing that, your `data` and `label` refer to two different batch (hence the fact that they look wrong).

You need to get them in the same call with:

```
data, label = sess.run([next_data, next_label])
```

Comment: That's exactly the problem! Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as resolved, so I'll be able to link to this for future duplicates :)